# MySQL - How to query for one value but default to another?

Tags: mysql

I asked the question about multiple rows in a previous thread, but now I need to know about a single row. This is an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE this = 5 LIMIT 1
```

But if there is no rows found then I would it to then find the record with a different value:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE this = 1 LIMIT 1
```

So what I want is, find a row with this having the value of 5, if not found then default to finding a row with a value of 1. How do I do that in a single query? Would an OR statement work like so?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE this = 5 OR this = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Would the order of the OR statement try to find any row with the value of 5, if found then it will stop and return the row? IF not found then look for 1 and then return that row? If not then how do I do this with a single query where it searches for one value, if not found defaults to find another value?

I was thinking this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE this IN(5,1) ORDER BY this ASC LIMIT 1
```

However this query would always return the value with 1 if both values were found right? So I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE this IN(5,1) ORDER BY this DESC LIMIT 1
```

But this would always return the value of 5 if both rows were found correct?

Comment: What do you want to happen if both rows are found?

Comment: @Ian Gregory Whatever was selected. So if the person selected to view a record from the database with a value of 5, but there is no record with the value of 5 then I want it to default load the value of 1.

Comment: What happens if you want to select where `this` has more than one value? Are you dynamically creating your statement or is this in a procedure etc?

Comment: @Ben this is only to return one value and only one value. Im using the IF statement for multiple rows. Im dynamically creating it, but I pass the query the current value that was requested and the default value to fall back on, so in this case 5 and 1 would be passed to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears to prioritize the search for 5 and only if not found then search for 1. Hence your second solution fits the requirement fine. It will return the value of 5 irrespective of if 5 is only found or both 5 and 1 exist.

the 2nd option

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE this IN(5,1) ORDER BY this DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think you are right. I might have over thought this. Because it would only be IN(5,1) if someone selected to view a row with a value of 5.

Comment: Your `order by` should be a `case` statement. There's no guarantee that `this` will be in the correct order.

Comment: @Ben that is why we have `ORDER BY this DESC`. This will ensure that the result is sorted in descending of `this` whatever rows are first found by MySQL.

Comment: @somnath, and what happens if the default is `50`? You then need to order by it `asc`, which means your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Ben the default will always been smaller than the record being requested.

Comment: @Ben the default is normally a row that is outside the general rows. I have used these scenarios earlier in our projects, and the default rows were either 1 or 0 or -1 etc. to help identify the special rows. The rest were the dynamic ones which could be chosen to be picked up by the passed query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 tab 
WHERE tab.this = IF((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                     FROM table1 
                     WHERE this = 5) > 0, 5, 1)
```

The query inside the IF is checking for the count.

I am not sure about the performance but I think this solves your issue.

Comment: just to clarify, IF([evaluate this],[use this if true],[use this if false])